# How to copy directories from one location to another in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Trying to write small Groovy script to copy directories (securely) from one location to another.

here is the code

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
def src = new File("/root/a/")
def dest = new File("/tmp/")
try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(src,dest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

not getting whats the wrong here. here is the error i am getting:

**what is the issue**

> root@artifactoryop2:~# groovy test2.groovy
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: /root/test2.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils  @ line 2, column 1.    import
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;    ^
>
> 1 error

do i need to manually import these packages?

Comment: Seems like you didn't add commons-io to your classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `commons-io` in a Groovy script, you may consider using [Grape to add a dependency](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) to a script file. All you need to add is

```
@Grab(group = 'commons-io', module = 'commons-io', version = '2.6')
```

on top of your `test2.groovy` script file.

Here is a simple demo based on your example.

*copy.groovy*

```groovy
@Grab(group = 'commons-io', module = 'commons-io', version = '2.6')
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

def src = new File("/tmp/a")
def dest = new File("/tmp/a2")
try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(src, dest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
$ tree /tmp/a2  
/tmp/a2 [error opening dir]

0 directories, 0 files

$ groovy copy.groovy

$ tree /tmp/a2      
/tmp/a2
├── dir1
│   └── file3
├── file1
└── file2

1 directory, 3 files
```

Comment: I used your script as it is but it is simply hanging. anything missing still ? The groovy version which i am using is : Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_222 Vendor: Private Build OS: Linux and maven version is : Apache Maven 3.3.9. please suggest